# I accidentally deleted modprobe.d can Ubuntu won’t boot what can I do?

Tags: boot, modprobe

Nvidia driver blacklisted the open source version and I found the file. Instead of deleting that one file I accidentally deleted the entire modprobe.d folder. I rebooted and now Ubuntu 20.04 won’t boot. What can I do?

Comment: I think the least complicated thing would be to install ubuntu in a new partition and copy that folder to the old one, you may need to update the new partition up to where your previous one was updated. I particularly use this quite often btw: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/626503/30352 this is a functional backup from root

Comment: You weren't specific as to what `modprobe.d` folder... my system has multiple (and I'd expect at least two, but likely more depending on how you use your system & programs installed)

Comment: /etc/modprobe.d